# Research topic- Evolutionary Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, advice, biology

I read *Evolutionary Dynamics* by Martin A. Nowak and became fascinated with evolutionary graph theory.

I'm mentoring an undergraduate student in the subject and would like to give him a research project in this field.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions?